# Reference Request: Why do regular stochastic matrices have limiting distributions?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes

In Pinsky and Karlin's *Introduction to Stochastic Modeling*, it is said without a proof that every regular stochastic matrix has a limiting distribution. More precisely,

> [image]

Does anyone have a reference for a proof of this statement?

Comment: This is simply Perron-Frobenius theorem for primitive matrices.

Comment: @Artem: Thanks for your comment! I didn't know that. I will come back latter once I figure out enough details.

Comment: A full proof of this theorem, without reference to Perron-Frobenius theorem, is given in the First course in Stochastic Processes by Karlin and Taylor, in Chapter 4.

Comment: @Artem: Thanks for the reference! I will check out that book to see details. I would accept your comments as an answer if you could post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This theorem is an immediate consequence of Perron-Frobenius theorem for primitive matrices (as given, e.g., Horn's Matrix Analysis).

A full proof of this theorem, without reference to Perron-Frobenius theorem, is given in the First course in Stochastic Processes by Karlin and Taylor, in Chapter 3.

(As a side remark I note that the book you are using is a "light" version of Karlin and Taylor two volume classic. I would suggest to switch to the original one, which is a quite deep exposition of the stochastic processes without any measure theory)

Comment: Would you elaborate which theorem are you referring to in Karlin and Taylor? I'm not able to find it in Chapter 4 of the second edition, which is about continuous time Markov chains.

Comment: @Jack It is Theorem 1.3 in Chapter 3.